# regex to remove everything after the last dot in a file

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex for removing everything after the last dot in a file. So far I've found ways to remove all text before the first dot, but I can't seem to find a way to select the end of the file. Could you help me on the way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/\.[^.]*?$/`, surely?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
\.[^.]*$
```

to match everything including and after the last dot. If you don't want to include the last dot, then you can use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\.)[^.]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex for search and replace

```
s/\.[^.]*$/\./
```

Comment: Actually just `s/[^.]*$//` does the same without a backref.

Comment: @tripleee that fails when there is no dot in a line, entire line will go away!

Answer (score 0):

```bash
gci | rni -new { $_.name -replace '([^.]*)$' }
```

This one is working,
This deletes everything behind the last dot, inclusief the dot.
It does delete the whole name, if no dots present, but Windows doesn't allow empty names, so it is not effected.

Answer (score -1):

On Bigquery, `r'([^.]+).?$'` works, if you want to remove the last dot.

Comment: What's with the final `.?`? It will remove the last dot if the last character is a dot.